# how can i share my edittext value via bluetooth?

Tags: java, android, android-service

i have one Edittext in my app and i want to do share EditText value via bluetooth to other phone in .txt file i am making note app i want to put this feature in my app to send my note via bluetooth so you friends can help me out in this i nothing know how can i do this so can any one of you give any idea or example or tutorial how can i do this i am very confuse in this so help me how will i do this .this is vary important for me .i am share my notes mail n sms bt don't know what to do to share this with bluetooth

help me.

thanxx